# When using a self-invoking function, why can't I pass references?

Tags: javascript, iife

I've been using the `IIFE` pattern for some modules recently and ran into a problem that I can't seem to find the answer to. In my project, I need to pass a couple of global variables in for usage. One of these is a global `googletag` variable which loads in with a default state and then changes once the external code has loaded in.

However, it doesn't seem to update because the pattern doesn't seem to create a reference but a copy. I've simplified the issue to below.

```
window.globalLevel = 'First';

var Module = (function(_g){
  function _stuff(){
    return _g;
  }
  return {
      get stuff(){
        return _stuff();
    }
  }
})(window.globalLevel);

// Initial state.
console.log("In Module:", Module.stuff);   // "First"
console.log("In Top:", window.globalLevel) // "First"

// After change.
console.log("--- Changing value ---")
window.globalLevel = 'Second'
console.log("In Module:", Module.stuff);    // "First"
console.log("In Top:", window.globalLevel)  // "Second"
```

**Can I do anything to fix this?** What kind of adaptations or considerations should I make? Should I just simply reference the `window.globalReference` directly in the module? Seems messy but it does seem to work.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04adLhxk/33/)

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have variable references. Arrays and objects are passed as references, and if you modify the object it will be reflected in all the variables that refer to it. But primitive types are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `_stuff` is currently returning the *argument that was initially passed*, the `_g`. So, when you change the global variable with `window.globalLevel = 'Second'`, the argument does not change, so the original argument is what gets echoed back. You can fix it by returning `window.globalLevel`:

```js
window.globalLevel = 'First';

var Module = (function(){
  function _stuff(){
    return window.globalLevel;
  }
  return {
      get stuff(){
        return _stuff();
    }
  }
})(window.globalLevel);

// Initial state.
console.log("In Module:", Module.stuff);   // "First"
console.log("In Top:", window.globalLevel) // "First"

// After change.
console.log("--- Changing value ---")
window.globalLevel = 'Second'
console.log("In Module:", Module.stuff);    // "First"
console.log("In Top:", window.globalLevel)  // "Second"
```

If `window.globalLevel` were an *object* and not a primitive, both the global variable and the argument would reference the same underlying object in memory, in which case your `_g` would work:

```js
window.globalLevel = { value: 'First' };

var Module = (function(_g){
  function _stuff(){
    return _g.value;
  }
  return {
      get stuff(){
        return _stuff();
    }
  }
})(window.globalLevel);

// Initial state.
console.log("In Module:", Module.stuff);   // "First"
console.log("In Top:", window.globalLevel.value) // "First"

// After change.
console.log("--- Changing value ---")
window.globalLevel.value = 'Second'
console.log("In Module:", Module.stuff);    // "First"
console.log("In Top:", window.globalLevel.value)  // "Second"
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `_g` parameter now.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That helps me make a lot of sense of how the scope is handled here. I'm still having issue on my live project but I no longer think it's related to this. The two libraries I need to pass in should work the same. One works now, the other fails so that one must be doing something strange on initialisation.